# Speeding up MovingMap of Dot

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have the following code (showing an insignificant simplification) that I really need to run many times for different ps (its length can be 10^7 or so) and wSize. Is there a way to speed this up using the fact that I have a special function inside MovingMap?

```
ps = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100000];
wSize = 100;
Σinv = Inverse@ToeplitzMatrix@CovarianceFunction[ps, {wSize - 1}];
MovingMap[#.Σinv.# &, ps, wSize - 1, "Periodic"];
```

Comment: Would it be prohibitive for you to do `tmp = Partition[ps, wSize, 1, -1];
MapThread[Dot, {tmp, tmp.Transpose[Σinv]}]`?

Comment: If you include partitioning into the total computation, do you get any significant gain time-wise?

Comment: I don't have a big computer to test this with (hence it's just a comment); I'm only going by the knowledge that it's more efficient to take matrix-matrix dot products than to incrementally build vector-by-vector.

Comment: Is there a way to compile this function? 

movingDot = Compile[{{ps, _Real, 1}, {wSize, _Integer}},
  With[{half\[CapitalSigma]inv = 
     Inverse@ToeplitzMatrix@CovarianceFunction[ps, {wSize - 1}]/2, 
    halfWSize = wSize/2}, 
   MovingMap[#.half\[CapitalSigma]inv.# &, ps, wSize - 1, 
    "Periodic"]]
  ]
movingDot[ps, wSize];

CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression {{2.9988,0.000143913,...,0.0015581,0.000759095,-0.000135168,<<37>>,-0.000601042,0.000877005,0.00026945,-0.000867925,0.00158341,0.000579952,<<50>>},{<<1>>},<<48>>,<<50>>} should be a machine-size real number.

Comment: Let me offer you a tip: if you are using a function that is not in [this list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101), then your function won't benefit from compilation.

Comment: Dot is in the list. Plus there is a related issue of how to do it in the first place, the effect notwithstanding.

Comment: Yes, but you stuffed things like `Inverse[]` and `CovarianceFunction[]` within `Compile[]`, which you now know to be pointless.